# Information Inequality theorem

Tags: information-theory

I was reading the information inequality theorem and got stuck trying to understand something. The highlighted portion says (2.85) becomes an equality if and only if $\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$ is a constant $c$. Since the sum of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ must each equal to 1, does that mean that the constant $c = 1$?

Because if $c$ takes any other value then either $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ will not sum to 1. I am also unable to prove that $(2.84) \implies (2.85)$ if $c \neq 1$.

[image]

Comment: Note that $\sum_{x\in A}p(x)=\sum_{x\in X}p(x)=\sum_{x\in X}q(x).$ But we don't know that $\sum_{x\in A}q(x)=1.$ So it could be $c\ne 1.$ (I don't know the book where the theorem is but: what if $q(x)=0,\forall x\in A$? Is not that possible?)

Comment: Thanks ! Then is it right to say that c can only take the value of 1 or 0 ? If 
 the probabilities don't need to sum to one and c can take on any value then I can't show, even with numerical examples, that (2.84) = (2.85) if for example c = 2. 

The book is called Elements of Information Theory. The image I took from page 28.

Comment: In the step $(2.84)\to (2.85)$ $c$ can be any positive constant. It is used that $\sum_i k_i\log a_i\le \log (\sum_i k_ia_i)$ where $\sum_ik_i=1$ (that is, Jensen's inequality applied to the concave function $\log$). Equality is achieved iff all $a_i$'s are the same. In your case $a_i=p_i/q_i.$ That is, they are all equal iff $q_i=cp_i$ for some positive constant $c.$ But you cannot get from that the value of the constant $c.$

Comment: I have found here https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597D/L03.pdf the conventions in case $q=0.$ (Thus $c$ can be any nonnegative constant. That is, $c=0$ is allowed.) I didn't know anything about this topic but it seems interesting.

Comment: Just an example: Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ with $p(1)=p(2)=1/2.$ Consider $X=\{1,\cdots, n\}$ with $q(1)=\cdots =q(n)=1/n.$ You get $q=2/np.$ That is, $c=2/n.$ If $n=2$ then $c=1$ but for $n>2$ it is $c\ne 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are probability mass functions. Therefore, $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} q(x)=1$. $D(p||q)=0$ if the equalities hold in **both** (2.85) and (2.87). According to (2.85), $q(x)=c p(x)$ for all $x \in A$, whereas (2.87) implies $\sum_{x\in{\mathcal{X}}}q(x)=\sum_{x\in A}q(x)=1$. Therefore, $$1= \sum_{x \in A} q(x) = c\sum_{x \in A} p(x)=c \iff c=1.$$

Comment: @mfl We need to satisfy both (2.85) and (2.87) for the equality to hold. Kindly check the updated answer and let me know if the argument in wrong.

Comment: In my opinion now it is correct. If we have equality in all steps then it must be $X=A.$ +1

Comment: Thanks @mfl. Your example was very nice though.

Comment: thank you both Math Lover and mfl your points have helped me understand !